# Mongoose not returning all properties in the schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This was my user Schema

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    name: String,
    thumb: String,
});
```

Recently I had to add some functionality and added this bit to the userSchema

```
flaggedConversations: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Conversation',
    default: []
}]
```

I haven't touched that property on any user, I've just added it to the schema for now.

Now, when I'm returning a user, It will return a document specific with the old schema. But I want to have that flaggedConversation property as well.

How do I do that?

Comment: Your old users likely don't have that property if you added it after the fact, you may need to write a database migration to add it to all the users. Have you tried making a new user? It likely will have the new property.

Comment: so I should do an update to all users. I tought mongoose will just show the property with the default value if it didn't exist :/

Comment: Not the original commenter, but yeah, you'll need to write a migration script. Basically, MongoDB doesn't enforce the schema on objects created before an attribute existed in the schema.

If you create a new user now, it should have the property, though.